# From shadertoy to own webgl program - Bug with 'iChannel0'

Tags: glsl, shader, shadertoy

I already compiled with success simply shaders from shadertoy. I hava implement volumetrix
but i cant handle: iChannel0

```json
 Shader Program compile failed:ERROR: 0:13: 'iChannel0' : syntax 
error


Shader Program compile failed:ERROR: 0:267: 'iChannel0' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:267: 'texture' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:267: 'st' :  field selection requires structure or vector on left hand side
ERROR: 0:267: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:267: '=' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'highp 2-component vector of float'
```

Looks like sampler .

Any suggestion?